# Activate Slider and Accordion Tab Content Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Since I didn't find any topic regarding this Ive decided to create it.
I'm struggling while trying to make this:
I have a slider and accordion tabs. The point is when the user clicks on the accordion tabs, the slider should change as the tab content does the same. If I click on tab1 the slider should jump to slider 1, if tab2->slider2, and so on.

What I've managed to 'do' is to move the slider (left/right) simultaneously with the tab content changing, but thats not what I need to have done...

Codepen with what I've achieved so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owRxwK

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000);

});


var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});


if($(window).width() > 768){



// Hide all but first tab content on larger viewports
$('.accordion__content:not(:first)').hide();

// Activate first tab
$('.accordion__title:first-child').addClass('active');

} else {

$('.accordion__content').hide();
};


$( ".accordion__content" ).wrapInner( "<div class='overflow-scrolling'>        
</div>" );
$('.accordion__title').on('click', function() {
$('.accordion__content').hide();
moveRight();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What isn't working correctly? What are you looking for? It works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. Edited the main post: The point is when the user clicks one of the accordion tabs, the slider should change as the tab content does the same. If I click in tab1 the slider should jump to slider 1, if tab2-slider2, and so on. @kirkpatt